# Firebase Database data collection

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, reference

I am using Firebase database for my project. For the last few days I tried to retrieve data from database but without luck. I tried many tutorials and questions from Stack.. Database looks like this:

Database structure

[image: Database structure]

My user class

[image: My user class]

I would like to retrieve information and store it in one of the strings..

My code is:
[image: First Code]

[image: Second Code]

Every time I receive value Null or an Error. I am not sure If I am using correct reference("Users").

Is there is easy way to retrieve users name and store it into the string? Thanks

Comment: Please replace the links to pictures of code and JSON with the actual text. In the case of the JSON you can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please don't show pictures of code.  It's much easier if you copy the code into your question and format it with a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to have same names for the fields in your database as in your model class. Looking at you model class, there are some things that you need to do. So, I'll provide a correct way to model your class.

```
public class UserModelClass {
    private String name, sureName, date, phoneNumber;

    public UserModelClass() {}

    public UserModelClass(String name, String sureName, String date, String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sureName = sureName;
        this.date = date;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {return name;}

    public String getSureName() {return sureName;}

    public String getDate() {return date;}

    public String getPhoneNumber() {return phoneNumber;}
}
```

In order to make it work, you need to remove all data from the database and add fresh one. There is a workaround when storing users in a Firebase database. Instead of using that that random key provided by the `push()` method, to use the `uid`. For that, I recommend you add the data as in the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
UserModelClass umc = new UserModelClass("Jonas", "Simonaitis", "today", "123456789");
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
uidRef.setValue(umc);
```

To read data, please use the following code:

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        UserModelClass userModelClass = dataSnapshot.getValue(dataSnapshot.class);
        String name = userModelClass.getName();
        String sureName = userModelClass.getSureName();
        String date = userModelClass.getDate();
        String phoneNumber = userModelClass.getPhoneNumber();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In one of my [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee) I have explained step by step how to use the model classes when using Firebase.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look. I will update with the result

Comment: Ok, waiting for your response.

Comment: Thank you Sir! It worked. Now I can store data into string! Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

First you have to do make these declarations:

```
private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
```

in onCreate you need to make smth like this:

```
mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();

mUserDatabase =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")        
.child(current_uid);

mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String name = dataSnapshot.child("uName").getValue().toString();

}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Now you have the user name in "name"

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference after implementing code provided above..

Comment: This code works for me. Can you please show me your code after implementation?

Answer (score 0):

First change userInformationActivity class variable names to match names in the database

example : name -> uName
          surname -> uSurname

then

```
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

   for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
       userInformationActivity user = dataSnapshot.getValue(userInformationActivity.class);
       Log.d("user Name is : " + user.uName);
    }

}
```